# How can I use xmlstarlet in groovy?

Tags: groovy, xmlstarlet

I have a bash script that uses xmlstarlet to process some xml. **I need to port bash script to Groovy (to use a Jenkins Pipeline) and I am having problems in the xml processing part**. I know GPath can be used but I am interested in using xmlstarlet if possible. This is a simplification of my bash script:

```
count=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//Result/Dataset[@name='PackageMap_Dataset']/Row)" /tmp/DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml)
echo count
```

In order to achieve it I tried this Groovy but script gets wrong output:

```
def count="xmlstarlet sel -t -v \"count(//Result/Dataset[@name='PackageMap_Dataset']\" DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml".execute().text
println "Number of detected DataSets: " + count
```

The simplified version with no @name has the same problem:

```
def count="xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//Result/Dataset' DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml".execute().text
println "Number of detected DataSets: " + count
```

Even this simply execution is failing, giving no output:

```
println "xmlstarlet".execute().text
def count= "xmlstarlet".execute().text
println "Number of detected DataSets: " + count
```

**How can I make this work?**

For reference here is xml

```
<Result>
<Dataset name='PackageMap_Dataset'>
  <queryname>getcoordmissinglocations</queryname>
 <Row>
  <superfilename>~foo::indexes::develop::LocationsToEnrich::Super</superfilename>
  <indexfilename>~foo::indexes::develop::LocationsToEnrich_20160912_143427</indexfilename>
 </Row>
 <Row>
    <queryname>getcoordmissingsoiltype</queryname>
    <superfilename>~foo::indexes::develop::SoilTypesToEnrich::Super</superfilename>
    <indexfilename>~foo::indexes::develop::SoilTypesToEnrich_20160912_143427</indexfilename>
</Row>
 <Row>
    <queryname>getngrmissinglatlong</queryname>
    <superfilename>~foo::indexes::develop::LatLongsToEnrich::Super</superfilename>
    <indexfilename>~foo::indexes::develop::LatLongsToEnrich_20160912_143427</indexfilename>
</Row>
</Dataset>
<Dataset name='Result 2'>
</Dataset>
<Dataset name='Result 3'>
</Dataset>
<Dataset name='Result 4'>
</Dataset>
</Result>
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated code to show errors as suggested by @cfrick

```
        //def proc = "xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//Result/Dataset)' DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml".execute();
        def proc = ["xmlstarlet", "sel", "-t", "-v", "\"count(//Result/Dataset)\"","DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml"].execute()
        def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
        def errorStream = new StringBuffer();
        proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, errorStream);
        println("OUTPUT: " + outputStream.toString());
        println("ERROR: " + errorStream.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: most likely there are error (e.g. xmlstartlet not in path, missing libs, ...).  check the return/stderr.  this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085198/git-command-works-in-terminal-but-not-from-groovy-script/33089101#33089101.  this also shows how to execute a list.  groovy is no shell, so there is no need to quote `'"...` - just split the params.

Comment: xmlstarlet is in the path and works well as I execute it from bash and works

Comment: imho your user being able to run it in a shell is no hard evidence, that there are no errors resulting from the execute.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Seems there is no errors

Comment: what is the return code?  why do you send errors to stderr and then print `errorStream`?  also split your exec call to be on the safe side. e.g. `["xmlstarlet", "sel", ...].execute()`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Corrected

Comment: Also split the exec with same output...Maybe is worth to forget about xmlstarlet and use GPath (XmlSlurper)?

Comment: have you removed the single quotes around the `count()`? would xmlstartlet just return it as a constant string?  `'` is only needed for your shell - not for spawning a process.  so its `[..., "count(...)", ...].execute()`. other than that: would i use the groovy means to read the xml? sure! but that does not answer the question at hand.

Comment: That did it! Taking away quotes from count(..). Exact line was def proc = "xmlstarlet sel -t -v count(//Result/Dataset) DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml".execute(). You should add an answer so I can accept it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy is just spawning new processes with arguments - and is no shell.  So there is no need to quote params (which shells need to leave params alone).  In this case the quoting of the query for `xmlstarlet` will make it think, one just wants a constant string back (see the `OUTPUT: count(//Result/Dataset)` in the question).

So just use `[].execute()` for proper argument separation, don't quote for a shell, don't use shell features (like piping, redirection, ...):

```
["xmlstarlet", "sel", "-t", "-v", "count(//Result/Dataset)", "DataPipeLineScript-output-step4.xml"].execute()
```

If you need "shellisms", use

```
["sh", "-c", "... | ... > 'quote weird files.txt' ..."].execute()
```

or how your shell is dealing with such an "eval me that line" scenario.